# how to have combination of keypress in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to get combination of key press on a page. I wrote a code

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 16 && e.which == 48) {
        alert('hi');
    }
}
```

but is not working.
How can I get the combination of two or more keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.shiftKey

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 48 && e.shiftKey) {        
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9xpbZ/1/)